# Override locale configuration file to customize price format

Tags: magento2, currency, locale, format

To reliably change the price format(group and decimal symbol) without having to override several classes or write plugins for them, I need to override the `en.xml` from the Zend library. Changing the XML directly covers several areas at once, like `list view`, `product view` or `knockoutJS`.

> vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml

I tried to override it via theme, but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can [replace](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace) this module with your own in composer.json file of your Magento 2 project. And in your module you can fix this price or number format. Small example of replace usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882201/how-does-the-replace-property-work-with-composer)